# How to ensure javascript using drupal behaviors is only run only certain pages?

Tags: 7, javascript

I have a custom module "mymodule" that will contain a javascript file that use drupal behaviors to do something.

Here is the file structure of the module. In the .info file i have added script[] = "js/mymodule.js"

mymodule:

- js/mymodule.js
- mymodule.info
- mymodule.module

One item i have noticed is that the javascript files runs all pages whenever the page is loaded. How can i limit the javascript to only run on pages where the javascript is needed?

Desired scenario:

1. If on any admin/* pages, do not run the javascript
2. If on any node/* page and if the page has a  tag with an id="target-id" (i.e. ), then run javascript.

Comment: Have you tried using hook_node_view_alter() to intercept the render array for the page and then using ['#attached']['js'] on the form? This link might be helpful:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1993228

Comment: @greendemiurge Yes i have tried that and i also tried to do hook_js_alter, but looks like your hook_node_view_alter suggestion works!